# Mantener una asignación de atributo a un espacio específico de un arraylist

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, poo

Necesito resolver este enunciado utilizando POO. Me pide que realice un programa que permita mostrar asientos ocupados para una película en una sala de cine utilizando una matriz de 8x9 y que además muestre que asientos han sido ocupados ya. Dado el hecho que apenas estoy iniciando en Python, no conozco todas sus opciones y no he podido encontrar una solución dentro de mi conocimiento.

Actualmente logré hacer el enlace con el asiento pero no logro mantener el estado que le asigno.

Este es el arreglo que estoy utilizando:

```
asientos = [['8A', '8B', '8C', '8D', '8E', '8F', '8G', '8H', '8I'],
        ['7A', '7B', '7C', '7D', '7E', '7F', '7G', '7H', '7I'],
        ['6A', '6B', '6C', '6D', '6E', '6F', '6G', '6H', '6I'],
        ['5A', '5B', '5C', '5D', '5E', '5F', '5G', '5H', '5I'],
        ['4A', '4B', '4C', '4D', '4E', '4F', '4G', '4H', '4I'],
        ['3A', '3B', '3C', '3D', '3E', '3F', '3G', '3H', '3I'],
        ['2A', '2B', '2C', '2D', '2E', '2F', '2G', '2H', '2I'],
        ['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E', '1F', '1G', '1H', '1I']]
```

Adjunto las clases que estoy utilizando:

```
class pelicula:
def __init__(self, titulo, duracion, edad_minima, director):
    self.titulo = titulo
    self.duracion = duracion
    self.edad_minima = edad_minima
    self.director = director

class cine(pelicula):
def __init__(self, titulo, duracion, edad_minima, director, precio, hora):
    pelicula.__init__(self, titulo, duracion, edad_minima, director)
    self.precio = precio
    self.hora = hora

def getDatosPelicula(self):
    print(f"Título: {self.titulo}\nDuración: {self.duracion}\nEdad mínima: {self.edad_minima}\nDirector: {self.director}\nPrecio: {self.precio}\nHorario: {self.hora}")

class asiento():
    def __init__(self, titulo, hora, estado):
        self.estado = estado

    def getEstado(self):
        return self.estado
```

Y por último, el proceso donde estoy intentando establecer la reserva del asiento:

```
m= randint(0, 7)
j = randint(0, 8)
print(m, j)

asientos[m][j] = asiento(cartelera[0].titulo, cartelera[0].hora, True) 
print(asientos[m][j].getEstado()) #Comprueba que el estado se aplicó
print(asientos[m][j]) #Aquí me imprime esto: <__main__.asiento object at 0x03DEC1A8>
asientos[m][j] = 'XX' #Reemplazo para demostrar que el asiento no esta disponible

for i in range (0, 8):
    for k in range (1, 9):
        print(asientos[i][k], end=" ")
    print()

print(asientos[m][j].getEstado()) #Aquí pierde el estado de reserva
```

Comment: ¿Y qué intentaste?

Comment: Para empezar, he intentado comprender como funciona el posiciona miento de una matriz bidimensional ya que necesito imprimirlo, además no se me ocurre como puedo enlazarlo, ejm. a la película 1 para que me diga que ciertos asientos están reservados, pensé en hace una clase nueva para reservas, pero no logro visualizarlo.

Comment: Divide y vencerás, dicen. Recomiendo empezar poco a poco, cada vez un paso. ¿Qué clase se te ocurre que podría definirse? ¿Y qué métodos debería tener?

Comment: pensé en una clase que llamaría "reserva" que tuviera como base mi clase cine (que a su vez tiene como base a la clase película), y de la clase cine, utilizar los atributos título y horario como referencia para poder definir un método que me diga que asientos ya han sido reservados para la película seleccionada y en un horario específico. Cabe aclarar que los asientos deben estar etiquetados como "1A, 1B... 1I" hasta la fila 8.

Comment: Eso ya es un buen comienzo y va en buena dirección. Dale a [edit] para mostrar estos detalles, junto con una pequeña implementación.